# monero-wallet-rpc: Transfer from sub-account?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, transfer

Is there an API call to transfer Monero from a specific sub-account?

"Transfer" API (https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer) does not appear to ask for a sub-account index/tag.

For example, I have 3 sub-accounts and want to send Monero from the 3rd one only, so that the other 2 sub-accounts have their balances remain unlocked.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, the developer guides are, at the time of writing, a bit outdated. Fortunately, however, a number of people are working on ensuring they will be up to date soon. One of those people is oneiric and I'll use the example from [his repository](https://github.com/coneiric/monero-site/blob/subaddress-docs/_i18n/template/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.md#transfer) to answer your question. See below for an updated guide on the `Transfer` RPC command:

> #### **Transfer**
>
> Send monero to a number of recipients.
>
> Inputs:
>
> - *destinations* - array of destinations to receive XMR:
>
>   - *amount* - unsigned int; Amount to send to each destination, in atomic units.
>   - *address* - string; Destination public address.
> - *account_index* - unsigned int; Transfer from this account index.
> - *subaddr_indices* - array of unsigned int; Transfer from this set of subaddresses.
> - *fee* - unsigned int; Ignored, will be automatically calculated.
> - *mixin* - unsigned int; Number of outpouts from the blockchain to mix with (0 means no mixing).
> - *unlock_time* - unsigned int; Number of blocks before the monero can be spent (0 to not add a lock).
> - *payment_id* - string; (Optional) Random 32-byte/64-character hex string to identify a transaction.
> - *get_tx_key* - boolean; (Optional) Return the transaction key after sending.
> - *priority* - unsigned int; Set a priority for the transaction. Accepted Values are: 0-3 for: default, unimportant, normal, elevated, priority.
> - *do_not_relay* - boolean; (Optional) If true, the newly created transaction will not be relayed to the monero network. (Defaults to false)
> - *get_tx_hex* - boolean; Return the transaction as hex string after sending
> - *get_tx_metadata* - boolean; Return the transaction metadata.
>
> Outputs:
>
> - *fee* - Integer value of the fee charged for the txn.
> - *tx_hash* - String for the publically searchable transaction hash
> - *tx_key* - String for the transaction key if get_tx_key is true, otherwise, blank string.
> - *amount_keys* - List of strings for the amount keys.
> - *amount* - Amount transferred for the transaction.
> - *tx_blob* - Transaction as hex string if get_tx_hex is true
> - *tx_metadata* - Transaction metadata string if get_tx_metadata is true.
> - *multisig_txset* - Set of signing keys used in a multisig transaction (empty for non-multisig).
>
> Example:

```
$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18082/json_rpc -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"0","method":"transfer","params":{"destinations":[{"amount":100000000,"address":"9wNgSYy2F9qPZu7KBjvsFgZLTKE2TZgEpNFbGka9gA5zPmAXS35QzzYaLKJRkYTnzgArGNX7TvSqZC87tBLwtaC5RQgJ8rm"},{"amount":200000000,"address":"9vH5D7Fv47mbpCpdcthcjU34rqiiAYRCh1tYywmhqnEk9iwCE9yppgNCXAyVHG5qJt2kExa42TuhzQfJbmbpeGLkVbg8xit"}],"mixin":4,"get_tx_key": true}}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

{
  "id": "0",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "fee": 48958481211,
    "tx_hash": "985180f468637bc6d2f72ee054e1e34b8d5097988bb29a2e0cb763e4464db23c",
    "tx_key": "8d62e5637f1fcc9a8904057d6bed6c697618507b193e956f77c31ce662b2ee07",
    "amount_keys":[],
    "amount": 300000000,
    "tx_blob": "",
    "tx_metadata": "",
    "multisig_txset": ""
  }
}
```